# JSON numeric value altered on php json_decode

Tags: php, json

When I JSON decoded the JSON in my php one of the numeric value is altered. My JSON is given below:

```
[
    {
        "__m":"m_0_7p"
    },
   100001572061234,
   null,
   "profile_friends",
   "pb_friends_tl",
   "\/ajax\/add_friend\/action.php",
   "",
   true,
   null,
   false,
   null,
   null,
   "friends_tab",
   []
]
```

On Json decode the output for the above json is

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [__m] => m_0_7o ) [1] => 1.000091378372E+14 [2] => [3] => profile_friends [4] => pb_friends_tl [5] => /ajax/add_friend/action.php [6] => [7] => 1 [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => friends_tab [13] => Array ( ) )
```

where '100001572061234' changed into 1.000091378372E+14. Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: When PHP displays numbers, it uses the php.ini precision setting to decide whether it should display all digits, or use scientific format..... this is a display setting, it doesn't change the value internally

Comment: However, that value is too large for a signed integer in 32-bit PHP, so it will be treated as a float in PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks. How can this be fixed......

Comment: From PHP 5.4.0 you have an option to use `$decoded = json_decode($encoded, false, null, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);` - http://nl1.www.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the info. Please post your answer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PHP displays numbers, it uses the php.ini precision setting to decide whether it should display all digits, or use scientific format..... this is a display setting, it doesn't change the value internally.

However, that value is too large for a signed integer in 32-bit PHP, so it will be treated as a float in PHP

From PHP 5.4.0 you have an option to use the [option flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to determine how large integer values are to be handled

```
$decoded = json_decode($encoded, false, null, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```